# wso2 api manager how to close http_access.log

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I finid that at {wso2am_home}repository/logs/ have logs:

```
 http_access_2013-10-28.log 
 tm.out wso2-apigw-errors.log
 wso2-apigw-service.log 
 wso2-apigw-trace.log 
 wso2carbon-trace-messages.log 
 wso2carbon.log
```

and I configure all the log4j.properties INFO to OFF. I don't know where to close the http_access.log.
I find when I call 1 time api,it write the http_access.log: gwmanager.apim-wso2.com:8280 - - - "GET /direct/1.0.5 HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1" 128.6.X.X:80 - - - "GET http://128.6.X.X:80 HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Synapse-HttpComponents-NIO so,as I call api time more and more ,the file is more and ---------- more big.

Do you know how to close the http_access.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable http access logs in WSO2 products then go to  catalina-server.xml which is located {CARBON_HOME}/repository/conf/tomcat directory, and remove the following property

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="${carbon.home}/repository/logs"
               prefix="http_access_" suffix=".log"
               pattern="combined" />
```

Please refer [this](http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.com/2013/07/configure-access-logging-in-wso2.html) for more details

Comment: thanks.And besides do u know the problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673219/wso2am-gateway-how-to-full-use-of-cpu